# combine two json files and keep the same structure javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm having some problems trying to create a JSON that contains information from a website that I scraped. I created two files and both have the same structure. I want to put them inside one JSON and keep the same structure for both. How can I do this?

My files look like this:

```
[
 {
   name: 'Jed',
   age: 23
   home: [
          {address: 5th AV 123
           coordinates: [{lat:12324,
                          long:1231
            }
          ]
        }
  ]
```

I have 10 of those with the same structure but with different information for every file. How can I create a main JSON that will contain all 10?

Comment: More more info, please! do you want to put every object into one array?

Comment: Just a heads up, the above is not JSON, it's a javascript array.   So, you can add objects to arrays using `Array.push` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to append objects to a specific array.  Likewise, use the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to pass the elements as params.

```
let array = anArray.concat(...anotherArray);
```

*Or pass multiple arrays as follow*

```js
let anArray = [{    name: 'Jed',    age: 23,    home: [{        address: "5th AV 123",        coordinates: [{            lat: 12324,            long: 1231        }]    }]}, {    name: 'Ele',    age: 36, home: [{        address: "5th AV 123",        coordinates: [{            lat: 12324,            long: 1231        }]    }]}],
    anotherArray = [{    name: 'Rick',    age: 21,    home: [{        address: "5th AV 123",        coordinates: [{            lat: 12324,            long: 1231        }]    }]}, {    name: 'Jade',    age: 42, home: [{        address: "5th AV 123",        coordinates: [{            lat: 12324,            long: 1231        }]    }]}],
    furtherArray = [{    name: 'Enr',    age: 21,    home: [{        address: "5th AV 123",        coordinates: [{            lat: 12324,            long: 1231        }]    }]}, {    name: 'John',    age: 42, home: [{        address: "5th AV 123",        coordinates: [{            lat: 12324,            long: 1231        }]    }]}];

console.log(Array.prototype.concat.call(anArray, ...anotherArray, ...furtherArray));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like this:

```
MainJson = [
              [
                 [Information From Site -1 related to A], 
                 [Information From Site -2 related to A]
              ], 
              [
                 [Information From Site -1 related to B],
                 [Information From Site -2 related to B]
              ]
           ]
```